# animate/add effects to stuff? JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could anyone please teach me how to add effects, say I would like some text to be faded when a button clicks, or make an alert box to do some cool stuff. I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to actually make it happen... Would love some help cheers!

Comment: Check their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). If you want to go with vanilla JS, use [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have at least some experience in CSS and JS a good and easy solution is to add/remove a CSS classes on a JS event and react to that.

This could look like this in the JS:

```
jQuery( '.triggering_element' ).click( function( {

    jQuery( '.receiving_element' ).addClass( 'effect' );

} );
```

and like this in the CSS:

```
.receiving_element {
    opacity: 0.0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.receiving_element.effect {
    opacity: 1.0;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

You can do all kinds of effects with this. Also pretty complex ones.

In the JS you can also use different events. Check out jQuerys [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this.

Sometimes it is a good idea to add the class to the body instead to the receiving element like `<body class="overlay_open">` ...

I think you get the point. If not, you have to learn some CSS and JS before you tackle things like effects ;)

Comment: Oh so ur supose to do it in the css file! I though Jquery had some "inbuilt effects" Thank you!

Comment: May be. But im pretty sure CSS animations are much more performant hardwarewise than jQuerys animate. Also the handling is way more elegant in my opinion.

Anyway ... if you want to do really fancy stuff you don't get far with any built in effects ;)

Comment: This is no tutorial platform ;) its for specific problems and specific solutions. If you create a question with some code and explain what you want to do or what the problem is i am pretty sure you get a helpful answer :)